# Repeated measures ANOVA for pre-post and post-post comparison + multiple comparisons problem

Tags: anova

In my experiment, subjects had to answer a number of unrelated questions before and after an intervention. We had two different interventions, and all participants underwent both interventions in separate sessions. So in each session, there is a pre and post intervention score for each question. For each question, I want to compare the pre and post score for each intervention, and I want to compare if there is a difference between the two interventions. For the latter comparison, I would subtract the pre score from the post score of each intervention and compare this difference between the interventions.

I analyzed my data by doing a separate repeated measures ANOVA for each question. In the post-hoc analysis, there are also comparisons made in which I’m not interested: namely comparing the two pre scores, and comparing the two post scores (remember I only wanted to compare the difference between pre-post for the two interventions). I have two questions regarding my analysis.

1. Is it a problem that I have these comparisons in which I’m not interested, since adding these comparisons in which I’m not interested increases the strictness of the post-hoc test? If yes, how I can avoid this?
2. How should I control for the multiple comparisons problem, as I’m doing the repeated measures ANOVA for around 15 different questions? I am reluctant to do a Bonferroni correction, as dramatically decreases the alpha level.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the format of the score ? When you say "and all participants underwent both interventions in separate sessions", it means that all participants underwent the 2 interventions right ? It means there will be a pre-1st intervention score, then a between 1st and 2nd intervention score, and then a post 2nd intervention score ?

Comment: Hi CaroZ, the score is a 7-point Likert scale, and all participants indeed underwent the 2 interventions. The pre interventions scores must be seen as a baseline to the post-intervention scores, so there is a pre 1st invervention score, a post 1st intervention score, a pre 2nd intervention score and a post 2nd intervention score.

Comment: Could you put the formula of your model in your question and a picture of a part of your dataset ?